# can we catch Packet Of HTTPservice of flex

Tags: actionscript-3, httpservice, flash-builder4.5, remoteobject, charles-proxy

Here i use [Charles web debugger Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to catch all packet which send/receive by HTTP Protocol and here, i declare, [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is HTTP monitor. after opening Charles i got all the packet which send from my browser. so i made a new application which call [GOOGLE](http://www.google.com/)'s URL. if i call [GOOGLE](http://www.google.com/)'s url by HTTPService then i can't catch any packet of My application and if i call [GOOGLE](http://www.google.com/)'s url by URLRequest then i got all packet in charles.

Question:

1. if i want to catch packet of HTTPService then which Tools/Application, i used ?
2. is it possible to catch packet of HTTPService/WebService/RemoteObject ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Fiddler](https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), free and very powerfull, you will be able to see all https/https trafics, add filters, etc.